# Minimum wire size for a 32Amp breaker

Tags: mains, circuit-breaker

Problem statement: Sailing boat with a 16A onboard breaker need to connect to a 32A onshore power supply.

What is the minimum cable size from the onshore 32A breaker to the onboard 16A breaker. Under normal operation it will not carry much current, but in the event there is a short on the cable between 32A breaker and 16A breaker then the cable need to survive long enough for the 32A breaker to trigger.

I've read standard is 6mm2 but seems 4mm2 may be sufficient for this use case, but would 4mm2 pass an inspection?

Background; some marinas offer 16A supply, but some only have 32A, so need a solution for the later. I know an alternative is external breaker box sufficiently sized, but I would prefer not to have too much additional equipment (as I will definitely need another breaker box to handle the rare case of only 63A supply).

Total cable length is less than 20meters, voltage: 240V.

Comment: If your boat has a 16 breaker, then that is what the manufacturer deemed necessary in light of what this boat requires for worst case current draw.

Comment: Within the boat that is true. But the problem is between the boat and the land power supply which is only fused at 32A , and as such would leave that cable at risk in case of a short on that circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Breakers protect the cables, that your boat is only 16A is irrelevant.
A 32A outlet requires a cable rated for 32A. No exceptions.

Using a reduction box 32->16A is the most suitable solution if you want to use a 16A cable.
eg: CEE 32 to CEE 16 is around €50.

Comment: Ready made reduction box with sockets or plugs and fuse does not seem to be available. However similar things are available and would require only small work, I will consider that. However I still think upgrading the cabling, plug and socket to 32A could be a decent alternative, I just not sure what the minimum wire size is for 32A, I've seen both 4mm2 and 6mm2 mentioned in this context.

Comment: @CaptainMJ Length and application area put thermal or mechanical reductions on cable ratings. See your local code.